# How can I lazy load a Vue Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to lazy load a Login component but after using `<Suspense>` and `<template>` with default and callback. It works normally but after the component is loaded the Loading component does not leave.

Here is my router.js code:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'


const Login = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(
                import ('./components/pages/auth/Login'),
            )
        }, 1000)
    })
}
const Register = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(
                import ('./components/pages/auth/Register'),
            )
        }, 1000)
    })
}

const routes = [{
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: Register,
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue is my root component file which is shown below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Suspense>
            <template #default>
                <RouterView />
            </template>
            <template #fallback>
                <div>
                    <h1>Loading....</h1>
                </div>
            </template>
        </Suspense>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components: {

    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Below is the result I get:
The black background is the loading which is not suppose to be there after component has loaded.
[Click to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zayfr.png)

Comment: What "Loading component" are you talking about? I only see `div > h1 > 'Loading....'` in the fallback slot.

Comment: The black background is part of `App.vue`, which wouldn't get removed.

Comment: It is the fallback part which is suppose to only show when the main default component is loading.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that's not a component. That's a slot. And that slot seems to be correctly replaced in your picture, as I don't see the text "Loading..." anywhere. You mention that the black background is not supposed to be there, but your styles apply `background-color: black` to all `div`s. There's a `div` at the root of `App.vue`, so that background would not disappear regardless of your `<Suspense>`.

Answer (score 2):

According with [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) all you need is to pass a function with dynamic import inside:

```
// replace
// import UserDetails from './views/UserDetails'
// with
const UserDetails = () => import('./views/UserDetails')

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes: [{ path: '/users/:id', component: UserDetails }],
})
```

Comment: I've tried this before it gave me the same result. It's not that my code is wrong.. I just added a delay of 1 seconds to the load time so that I can clearly observe the differences.